# Travis not picking up new commits

Tags: travis-ci

I have a travis build job configured at:
https://travis-ci.org/caffeinated-expert/frisbee

I have been pushing commits but travis does not pick them up.

Answer (score 14):

That usually happens when you have syntax errors in your `.travis.yml`. You can check your travis config using the web app at http://lint.travis-ci.org/. (There's more information [here](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/travis-lint/))

When I run the `.travis.yml` from your development branch, I get

`syntax error: (<unknown>): did not find expected '-' indicator while parsing a block collection at line 5 column 3`

Comment: Seems it's been deprecated, which is a pity

Answer (score 0):

I just had this issue, receiving the following error after not making a build for the first time in 2 months.

> "Oh no! An error occurred. The job could not be restarted"

and opening up the console, a 403 was reported.

According to [this thread](https://travis-ci.community/t/oh-no-an-error-occurred-the-job-could-not-be-restarted/11193/12) it was necessary for me to select a **payment plan** (which in my case, was the 'free' plan)

To select your plan:

- Click the drop-down on the top-right
- Click "Settings" option
- Click the "Plan" tab
- Select your plan